# VIM: Insert a line number, with a space after

Tags: vim

I need to insert the line number before each line of text using Vim, and there has to be a space after the line number. For example, if this was TestFile:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
Morbi nunc enim, vehicula eget, ultricies vel, nonummy in, turpis.
```

It should look like this

```
1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
2 Morbi nunc enim, vehicula eget, ultricies vel, nonummy in, turpis.
```

I have been using the command `:%s/^/\line('.')/` with a number of variations, but I cannot figure out how to get the space at the end.

Any ideas?

Comment: @ncphilips: if Johnsyweb's answer solved your trouble, please accept his answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You were very close!

This substitution will do the job by [concatenating](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#expr-.) the string `' '` to the line number:

```
%s!^!\=line('.').' '!
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was using + as the appending character and getting errors

Comment: @ncphillips: Happy to help. The string concatenation expression is `.`. I've added a link to relevant section of the documentation.

Comment: Probably because you have ! instead of /

Still, I understood what you meant and it worked.

Comment: `!` is a perfectly valid character to delimit the substitution (see http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#E146 ). If my answer helped you, please mark it as accepted so that it may help others.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably easiest with an external tool:

```
:%!nl -ba -w1 -s' '
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a macro. First make sure you have a 0 before the first line and have your cursor placed on it:

```
0 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
Morbi nunc enim, vehicula eget, ultricies vel, nonummy in, turpis.
foo
bar
etc...
```

Then perform this key sequence to store the right macro in register a: `qaywjP0<C-A>q`.
Now press `@a` to execute the macro. Use a quantifier to execute it multiple times.

Type `:help q` to find out more about recording macro's.